# SHGetSpecialFolderPath Error

Tags: visual-c++

I want to get the location of the program files folder, So i am using

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL,Path_variable,CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES,FALSE)
```

I don't see anything wrong here but I am getting the error

> error C2065: 'CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES' : undeclared identifier

I am using VC++ 6.0 and OS is WIN 7. What is the problem here ?. If I run the same code using Visual Studio 2005 , I am not getting any error.

Comment: Are you using vs05 in win7 or other os?

Comment: VS in XP but when i try with vc++ 6 in xp same error occurs.

Comment: Once try to put 0x0026 at the place if 3rd parameter.I hope it will work!

Comment: I tried , the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

**This is alternative of your problem,You can use it**

Try to read the registry entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir
```

At this position the path of the program files reside.

**EDIT:**

```
CRegKey key;
CString value = "ProgramFilesDir";
ULONG len = 255;
CString buffer;
long nError = key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion",KEY_READ);
if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
}
key.QueryStringValue(value,buffer.GetBufferSetLength(len),&len);
```

Now the buffer will contain the path

For more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2wz0ekh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: How to do access the registry entry..?

Comment: Is Key an object for CRegKey class..? Did u test this code in vc6.0 , Again the same problem it works in vs2005 bt not in vc6.0

Comment: yes,Sorry I forget:P                                                              Now Look at the edit part................

Comment: And also include this line #include <AtlBase.h>

Comment: thts ok , being a programmer I should know tht.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please include entire code snippet you use to retrieve this folder?

I just tested it in the MFC application using VS 6.0 SP3 on XP Sp3 and it works like a charm.
For this to work on earlier systems you have to have IE 4 or later installed.

**vikky:**

Your code will not work in VS 6.0. 
QueryStringValue member of the CRegKey does not exist.

Besides i think that using SHGetSpecialFolderPath should work.
Also, registry can change but the result of the SHGetSpecialFolderPath call will not.